# Infinite parameters in express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have implemented react router with recursion parameters. something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/embed/00y0942knw?codemirror=1&source=post_page-----cdc6a4bb8e1d----------------------)

i have server with express where i try to handle route **/someRoute/:recursiveParameter?**

```
 router.get('/someRoute/:recursiveParameter?', async (req, res, _next) => { whatever here })
```

but i am not able to catch route with more parameters eg.

`localhost://someRoute/param1/param2`

I can't find any solution for this. Also I can't write route like someRoute/:param1/:param2 because I don't know how many parameters there will be.

How can I solve this with number of unknown dynamic parameters in a route with express? thx

Comment: How about just use query parameters

Comment: express matches routes using regular expressions, so you should be able to match the start of the route, then use `req.originalUrl` to do custom matching.

Comment: How about wildcard params like : ```router.route('/:mypath*')```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use wildcards like * in your routes, it also supports Regex, working example:

```
app.get('/someRoute/*', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params[0]); 
});

// GET /someRoute/v2/this/route
// Output: v2/this/route
```

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for something like this?
`router.get('/someRoute/.*?', async (req, res, _next) => { whatever here })`

Comment: thx for answer.  router.get('/\/someRoute\/.*?/', async (req, res, _next) => { whatever here }) this was working but i am going to use someRote/* solution

Answer (score 1):

Please use regular expression match for the above scenario.
Example:

```
router.get('/someRoute/*', async (req, res, _next) => { whatever here })
```

```
//Correct matches: 
/someRoute/a/b/c
/someRoute
/somRoute/something
```

Also, if you already know the maximum possible number of arguments, you can use "?" which indicates it's optional.

Example:

```
router.get('/someRoute/:arg1?/:arg2?/:arg3?/:arg4?', async (req, res, _next) => { whatever here })
```

Refer Express Routing Official Docs:
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: thx, /someRoute/* is working, but ill accept answer what was befor yours