# Express.js - Allow infinite subroutes, but at least one

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I want to allow any subroute after `/example/...`.

Example of valid URLs:

- /example/one
- /example/one/two
- /example/one/two/three

But doing this:

```js
server.get('/example/*', (req, res) => {
   // ...
})
```

Is also allowing `/example` without any subroute. And I want to avoid this. How can I do it? Is there any way without using regex?

Thank you so much!

Comment: What would you like to happen when someone goes to `/example` without any sub route?

Comment: I'm using Next.js, so it's going to render the default `pages/example.js` page

Comment: ...and you don't want that to happen?

Comment: yes, but for `/example/some/subroute` I want to handle in a different way. What I want is that the above code don't enter for `/example`, only for `/example/subroute`

Comment: Does this answer your question ? [Infinite parameters in express server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57670931/infinite-parameters-in-express-server)

Comment: No, the proposed solution of your link is just the same code I added above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply define two routes - one for `/example` and another for all `/example`-subroutes, you need to make sure the order is correct though:

```
app.get('/example', (req, res) => {     
    // render default page
});

app.get('/example/*', (req, res) => {
   // do other stuff
});
```

Comment: Yes, I know... But I want to avoid to add an `app.get('/example', handler)` above... But anyway, your answer is valid. Thank you